# Communicator 2007 R2 saved conversation in Outlook has LARGE filesize

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, ms-office-communicator

I recently upgraded from Communicator 2007 to 2007 R2.  I notice that the conversations saved to Outlook Conversation History folder **occupy much more space (~ 10x-20x)** than they used to.  For example, a simple 5-line convo between 2 people would take 4K in Communicator 2007.  In R2, the same convo takes 50K. That might seem small, but I'm a big Communicator user, and my work inbox has a quota. I know, I can archive stuff. But I'd like to know why the big increase in size, and is there a way around it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I've seen so far, the size increase is due to the inefficient CSS styles being generated and stored in Outlook. When you look at the "raw" file in a text editor, there seem to be a huge amount of nested HTML tags

However, I'm not sure if which software is generating the HTML/XML or why there is a sudden change. And I have not seen any posts about it from Microsoft.

Comment: Anyone can cross reference that with LYNC? As Communicator R2 is outdated - Lync may have fixed this.